# Getting only the string value from returned Get-ADUser Array

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wrote a small Forms GUI in Powershell and in there I have a combobox with emails of users from an AD.
Now I got an event on SelectedIndexChanged where I want to display more informations about the selected user in a label. Since i have a unique email as a filter there's always just one returned object with Get-ADUser.

My problem is that Get-ADUser returns an array of strings when i use `select cn` and even with `Out-String` it returns a string with the formatting of a returned array.

I don't want to manually remove the `@{cn=}` when i get the returned string. So is there a more effective way to get JUST the value of the returned string array?

This is what I tried:

```
$label_name.Text = Get-ADUser -Properties mail -Filter {mail -like $comboBox_User.Text} | select cn | Out-String
```

the returned string looks like this:

```
cn
-
foo (returned name)
```

the return i was expecting:

```
foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is missing the `cn` property so make sure that's included in `Get-ADUser` as it's not returned by default. Expand the CN property. You don't need `| Out-String` with that.

`$label_name.Text = Get-ADUser -Properties mail,cn -Filter {mail -like $comboBox_User.Text} | Select-Object -expand cn`

Comment: I used `select -ExpandProperty cn` but it works perfectly now. Thank you